# Unable to change dateFormat in jquery ui datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I want to change the dateFormat of datepicker in dd-mm-yy. If I change the date format it is showing please enter a valid date. I have seen other solution but nothing is working.

thank you.

my form

```
   <link href="{{ url('css/jquery-ui.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

    <div class="row text-center">

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      Start Date

      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <input  placeholder="Start Date" class="form-control date" name="startdte" readonly>

      </div>
      </div>

        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
         End Date
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <input  placeholder="End Date" class="form-control date" name="enddte" readonly>
      </div>
      </div>

        </div>


 </div>
</div>

<script src="{{url('js/jquery-ui.min.js')}}"></script>  

     $('.date').datepicker({

           //dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd",   this one working
            dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"  this is not working 

     });


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7qqg.png
```

Comment: it something that needs to do with your validation logic and not with datepicker

Comment: @SureshKamrushi I am not performing any validation for date this error I am getting from datepicker

Comment: @matheenulla: can you share any snippet where we get this error comes ?

Comment: can you share the html what you have written and what JS files are included in your page

Comment: @SureshKamrushi ya sure I am modifying my question

Comment: have you used bootstrap date picker or simple jquery datepicker

Comment: i am using jquery date picker

Comment: have you check any console log

Comment: can you attach that error in your question? if possible add console log image in your question and put whole code how you include jquery and datepicker js

Comment: @Jinesh I have pasted the links

Comment: Finally I found this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41435873/where-trigger-the-please-enter-a-valid-date-in-jquery-validate-js/41436252

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem is solved. I was getting this error from `jquery validation plugin` not in `datePicker`. In jquery validation plugin is not accepting the format dd-mm-yyyy. to change this U have to do  modification in `jquery.validation.min.js`

for more informaton  [Where trigger the "Please enter a valid date." in jquery.validate.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41435873/where-trigger-the-please-enter-a-valid-date-in-jquery-validate-js/41436252)

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you have already initialized the datepicker in a previous section of code, so you may need to use this to set the value:

```
$('.date').datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd-mm-yy");
```

Comment: If I use this code means I am not getting a date picker. This is not working