# jquery validation plugin with jquery datepicker error(Please enter a valid date)

Tags: jquery, laravel, datepicker

I'm using a `jquery` validation plugin for form validation. I'm validating the date. But I'm getting the error like

> please enter the valid date

if I change the Jquery datepicker format. I don't know where it is coming from.

I'm using `jquery ui date picker`.

```
 $('.date').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        changeMonth:true,
        changeYear:true
 });
```

form

```
<form method="post" id="policiesform" action="{{ url('createpoli') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      Start Date

      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <input type="text"  placeholder="Start Date" class="form-control date" name="startdte" readonly>

      </div>
      </div>

        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <div class="form-group">
      <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
         End Date
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
      <input  placeholder="End Date" class="form-control date" name="enddte" readonly>
      </div>
      </div>

        </div> 
   </div>
</form>
```

validation

```
$('#policiesform').validate({
        rules: {
            startdte: {
                required:true,
            },
            enddte: {
                required:true,
            },


        },
        messages: {
            startdte: {
                required:"Start Date is Required",

            },
            enddte: {
                required:"End Date is Required",

            },  

        }
    });
```

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41435873/where-trigger-the-please-enter-a-valid-date-in-jquery-validate-js/41436252

Comment: do you use the moment js ?

Comment: @Maraboc No I am using simple jquery validation plugin

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth Yes you are right I am also getting the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have downloaded the jquery validation plugin then you have to make changes in
`jquery.validate.min.js`, for more information you can find here [Where trigger the "Please enter a valid date." in jquery.validate.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41435873/where-trigger-the-please-enter-a-valid-date-in-jquery-validate-js/41436252)

Answer (score 0):

try start-date, end-date id's instead of class

Start Date

```
$('#start-date').datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
        changeMonth:true,
        changeYear:true
 }).on('change', function() {
        $(this).valid();  // triggers the validation test
        // '$(this)' refers to '$(".date")'
 });
```

End Date

```
$('#end-date').datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
            changeMonth:true,
            changeYear:true
     }).on('change', function() {
            $(this).valid();  // triggers the validation test
            // '$(this)' refers to '$(".date")'
     });
```

Comment: please enter a valid date

Comment: Hi matheen ulla, create separate startDate, endDate id instead of class